# Could not find a declaration file for module 'reactstrap'

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm lost, i tried to run my older react project, but now reactstrap and react-animation-components are not working.

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-animation-components'. 'c:/Users/user/zreact/node_modules/react-animation-components/lib/react-animation-components.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-animation-components` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-animation-components';`ts(7016)

The same goes with react-animation.I tried `npm i --save-dev @types/react-animation-components` but that changes nothing.

Comment: try to remove your node_modules and your package-lock.json and then install all dependencies.

Comment: it didnt help. What i did before this error was `npm install react-scripts --save`.